# I want to trigger an event once when scrolled into view with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I am working on this little code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      windowHeight = $(window).height(),
      elem = $('#coverage-area-load-trigger').offset().top,
      final = elem - windowHeight,
      distance = final - scrollTop;
  if(distance < 0){
    console.log('Load Now');
  }
});
```

How should I write this so that "Load Now" only is logged one time?

I am going to replace the "Load Now" console log with this:

```
$('#coverage-area').attr('src', 'https://www.google.com/maps/...');
```

To trigger the "coverage-area" iframe to load when it's coming into view.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That piece of code works? The only problem is that the console.log gets triggered multiple times?

Comment: Correct.  When the "coverage-area-load-trigger" div comes into view, it console.logs "activate" for every pixel that is scrolled.  So if the div is on screen, and you keep scrolling, it will log "activate" over and over.  I just need it to log "activate" one time then never again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a variable that checks if the event was triggered like so:

```
var coverageAreaTriggered = false;
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if (!coverageAreaTriggered ){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      windowHeight = $(window).height(),
      elem = $('#coverage-area-load-trigger').offset().top,
      final = elem - windowHeight,
      distance = final - scrollTop;
    if (distance < 0) {
      console.log('Load Now');
      coverageAreaTriggered = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  ...
  if(distance < 0){
    console.log("load now");
    $(window).off("scroll");
  }
```

});

The off, when called, removes the event handler. Thus, after it has triggered, it removes itself.

Comment: Definitely a better approach

Comment: I don't know about better, really - with your way, you still handle scrolling for other page elements. For example, if parallax scrolling was a thing, my way just broke it, while yours wouldn't.